# concept of domains and subdomains for small database entities

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

recently I learned a concept called by my teacher "Domains and subdomains" in which small tables are generalized in which less than 5000 data or rows will be saved, I show you an example:

**Entities**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xhkl.png)

**level dates:**

```
   id_level  description
      01      continent
      02      country
      03      state
```

**domain dates**

```
id_domain       detail    level    parent
      01       America      01       -
      02         USA        02       01
      03        Europe      01       -
      04        Africa      01       -
      05          UK        02       03
      06        Aberdeen    03       05
```

**If this concept has another name, it would help me a lot to know it.**

Then we had to make an abstraction of this and take it to common entities like the following example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVgnP.png)

**level dates:**

```
    id_level description
       01     address
       02     phone
       03     gender
```

**domain dates**

```
id_domain detail         level parent
    01    male            03    -
    02    female          03    -
    03    mobile phone    02    -
    04    home address    01    -
    05    home phone      02    -
    06    work address    01    -
```

**Person dates**

```
id_person name phone_type phone_value address_type adress_value gender
    01    Jhon     03       39249927     06          a place...   01
    02    Mary     05      2489540300    04         a place2...   02
```

**but i get an error saying, the duplicate key name when i try to make the relation**

```
ALTER TABLE person
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_DOMAIN
FOREIGN KEY (address_type)
REFERENCES domain(id_domain);
```

**Error**

```
Duplicate key name 'FK_PERSON_DOMAIN'
```

**Something I should add is that I already did the nesting with phone_type, after this it does not let me nest the other two attributes as shown in the diagram**

This is the relationship that worked perfectly:

```
ALTER TABLE person
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_DOMAIN
FOREIGN KEY (phone_type)
REFERENCES domain(id_domain);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call those "lookup tables." They usually have characteristics of having a small number of rows, and also they don't change frequently. They may have an integer `id` primary key, or they may have a natural primary key.

The error you got about the duplicate key name is caused by the rule that constraint names must be unique across all tables in a schema. In other words, there must be only one constraint named `FK_PERSON_DOMAIN_PERSON` in the schema.

You said you already created a constraint with this name for the `phone_type` column. If you want another constraint for the `address_type` column, you must choose a different name for that constraint.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
ALTER TABLE person
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_PHONE
FOREIGN KEY (phone_type)
REFERENCES domain(id_domain);

ALTER TABLE person
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_ADDRESS
FOREIGN KEY (address_type)
REFERENCES domain(id_domain);
```

See that the constraint names are different.

Comment: I tell you, I already made a FOREIGN KEY with phone_type and after this it won't let me put the same id again, however in my logic I must make the FOREIGN KEY with 3 attributes, I'm going to edit it so they know it too

Comment: I edited my answer above, hopefully it is more clear now.